# Thief Minigame. Check inventory for specific amount and apply effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a Minigame for Minecraft. I want a thief to get gold by standing near a gold block.

Once the player has more then a specific amount(say he has 64 gold) an effect will be applied to the player such as Slowness.
i already tried command blocks using some Video's on youtube But that didnt work at all

The game is team based so I only want a specific team to be able to get the gold.

Comment: so... which part are you struggeling with exactely?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: im struggling with the part where a command block has to detect players 
close by one spefic block (in this case gold) 
but also how to check on a player how much gold they have inside there inventory

Comment: @coasterrider Did you accept my answer because I said you can do it while giving out the gold? While that is true and probably the best solution for your case, the general case you asked for in this question is better answered with IronAnvil's answer.

Comment: i made a error kinda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, it uses a scoreboard and commandstats.  It will use 3 command blocks in a repeating chain:
[image: Blocks]

First you need to manually create a scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Amount dummy
```

I also recommend disabling command block output to prevent chat spam with command:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

The first block clears the item of your choosing with an amount of 0.  It clears no items from the inventory, but it still affects the specified item.  The second block stores how many items were affected in the objective `Amount`.  This objective now has total number of the item specified in the first command block that is in the players inventory.  The third block applies the effect

First block is <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
clear @a minecraft:gold_ingot 0 0
```

Second block is <kbd>Chain</kbd> <kbd>Conditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
stats block ~1 ~ ~ set AffectedItems @a Amount
```

Third block is <kbd>Chain</kbd> <kbd>Conditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
effect @a[score_Amount_min=100] minecraft:slowness 1 2
```

This will apply level 2 slowness effect to any player with 100 or more gold ingots.

**Note:** The coordinates in the second command block should be the coordinates for the first command block.  It could be X or Z +/- 1.

---

Here is a method of making the gold block give the player gold ingots.  Set a gold block where ever you want it to be.  Jump on top of it and use the command:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~-1 ~ {Tags:["TheftBlock"],Invulnerable:1,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1}
```

Set another <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> command block and give it command:

```
execute @e[tag=TheftBlock] ~ ~ ~ give @a[r=1] gold_ingot 1
```

This will give any player a gold ingot every tick they are standing near the gold block.  Once they get more then 100, the above command blocks would apply a slowness effect.

You mentioned only a specific team being able to 'steal' the gold.  In that case, just change the last command block command to:

```
execute @e[tag=TheftBlock] ~ ~ ~ give @a[r=1,team=TEAMNAME] gold_ingot 1
```

Change `TEAMNAME` to the team name of the thief team.

---

If you ever decide to destroy the entire contraption, you will need to destroy the invisible armor stand.  Use the command:

```
/kill @e[tag=TheftBlock]
```

Comment: Oh, right, stats. I always forget what all is possible with it. I thought you have to test for every single slot. But the other part of my answer is still correct: He wrote "I want a thief to get gold by standing near a gold block.", so he can just attach a `scoreboard players add <selector> <score> 1` to whatever system gives out the gold.

Comment: I would agree with you, it is much simpler to add to a scoreboard.  The upside to this system is that it is a live tracking of the item count as long as the command blocks are loaded which allows them to throw out the gold if that is ever needed for his game.  He doesn't say what is to happen at the other end so if they are supposed to run it to a chest, the effect will stop whenever they dump enough of the gold.

Comment: There are many possible details important for my solution, yours just answers the question in the title, which makes it applicable for all possible applications of it.

Answer (score 0):

+++++ I was wrong with the statement in the spoiler, the other answer works. +++++

> It's very tedious to really detect the amount of one item in a player's inventory, you need more than 2000 commands.

Since you're already giving the player the gold with commands, you can better set the score at that moment. But how exactly you do that depends on your setup, you have to come up with a way yourself.